# Website not loading properly inside WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to load this url http://www.uramus.com inside an Application with WebView. The problem is i'm getting just the background of the page (blue screen)  with no elements of the Webpage loaded. While this never happens in Android default browser, which loads the page completely. Why does this happen?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.hide();

    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pg);

    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
    wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);        
    wb.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    //wb.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());

    wb.loadUrl("http://www.uramus.com/#/new-releases");
}
```

Comment: your site working on flash??

Comment: Actually the website uses Spotify and Youtube Apis

Answer (score 3):

in your webview you are getting  exception **uncaught typeerror cannot read property**

this is solved by this line of code.

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);;
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help. Can you please explain why does this happen?

Comment: Also i have added this line. Only the welcome message is displayed and other elements aren't displayed.

Comment: where you are running your app emulator or device.?

Comment: run your apk on device it will display .

Comment: I'm running it on the device only

Comment: i use this code and its working for  me webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 
  webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);;
  webview.loadUrl("http://www.uramus.com/");

Comment: For me the complete page isn't loading.. only the Welcome message is displayed on top. I have used the same code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96305/discussion-between-devmarc-and-vishal-jangid).